# How to convert an HTML page to PDF in PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

```
<?php
    include ('mpdf/mpdf.php');
    $mpdf = new mpdf;
    ob_start();
?>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
       My various content with table, dropdown menu and 2 include files.
    </body>
</html>

<?php 
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;
?>
```

Wondering why this function doesn't work and will only output empty pdf file. I have tried many ways but it just doesn't work. I have placed this function at the beginning of my code but it always outputs an empty file.

Comment: You are buffering to the var $html and don't use it later. Somehow you have to give it to the $mpdf object. But since you are not telling, which libary you are using, noone can help you. Check your libaries excamples.

Comment: How does a question that could be easily answered by reading the `mpdf` library's docs get upvotes? @Daniel is right, you need to find the mpdf method that you can pass `$html` to

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:-

```
 <?php 
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        // You need to write html
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        // define path of your output file and set mode 'F' for saving
        $mpdf->Output('filename.pdf','F');
        exit;
 ?>
```